# Connecting MongoDB compass to MongoDB running on another machine

Tags: database, mongodb, ubuntu, database-connection, mongodb-compass

I built a Node.js RestAPI that communicates with a MongoDB. I've deployed this into a host machine. Everything is working, I can use my application and communicate with the RestAPI that writes data into the MongoDB database.

However, I'm trying to get the MongoDB compass on my PC to connect to the MongoDB on the host machine, so I can see the DB in a more user-friendly way, but no matter what I try, I can't get compass to connect with the DB on the host machine.

Mongod is running on 127.0.0.1:27017 on the host machine but accepts external requests. The server has a public IP address, which is in use in the application and works, however, no matter what hostname I try it always says MongoDB isn't running on provided host and port. The host machine is running Ubuntu 16.04.

Can anyone please tell me what are the parameters I need to fill on compass in order to get it to connect?

I've read the documentation, but to no avail.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to connect to your `MongoDB` from difference machine, I think maybe some reasons make this happen:

1. Do you have make sure Port `27017` is already open for remote access on your Ubuntu firewall setting (UFW)?
   If no, You can try `ufw allow 27017`. But I don't really recommend this way for security reason; You can do Port forwarding by `iptable`.
2. Do you have turn on `Remote Access` in your MongoDB configuration? [Check This Out](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-allow-remote-access/)

Comment: From the link you gave, I take it I have to check my machine IP and add it do the bindIP in mongod.conf on the server machine. Is that it?

Comment: @DiogoMelo That's right. You have to add your client IP into your `mongod.conf` file. And don't forget to open your `PORT 27017` on the firewall setting.

Comment: So I did `ipconfig` on my client machine, got the IPV4 address, added it to the bindIP on `mongod.conf`and tried to connect and still the same error! On the hostname what should I put?

Comment: @DiogoMelo well, I have no idea what your ip is. Let's figure out that first, Is the server and client in the same network? If yes, you have to use internal ip address to access your `MongoDB server`. If no, you have to make sure your router setting that port haven't been block by router.

Otherwise, just put your server ip address in the hostname field.

Comment: Something is serioulsy wrong, as I have just commented the `bindIP` line and I still can't connect using the host machine public IP

Comment: just to be sure : when you did you tries, you restart your mongod after that?

Comment: Yes, but I have now been able to connect. I had to restart the server.
However this only works with `bindIP` commented out, which is not what I'm looking for.
On my client I ran `ipconfig` and added both ethernet ipv4 address and VPN ipv4 adress to `mongod.conf` on my host machine, but none works. I've done `ufc allow 27017` so I don't  know why I can't connect!

Comment: I found out why I can't connect when I add both IP's. What happens is, when I add an IP to `mongod.conf` I cannot start the mongod service for some reason... So the Compass error saying that no service is running is correct! I have no time to work this out, so I'll just comment the `bindIP` line everytime I need to see the DB. Thank you anyway @MaxChou and @matthPen